# El día siguiente hábil al (después del día) de la recogida del paquete

Tags: gramática

¿Tienen igual significado las siguientes frases?

> "Aquellos envíos urgentes que realices online se entregarán el día siguiente hábil al de la recogida del paquete"

y

> "Aquellos envíos urgentes que realices online se entregarán el día siguiente hábil después del día de la recogida del paquete"

La oración tiene que ver con el envío de paquetes.

Comment: You should say: "...el día hábil siguiente al de la recogida/recolección del paquete" OR "...el día hábil después de(l día de) la recogida/recolección del paquete".

Comment: ... el día que sigue la fecha de entrega.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparte del hecho de que deberías decir *el día hábil siguiente* en vez de *el día siguiente hábil*, sí, ambas oraciones significan lo mismo, pero la segunda contiene algunas redundancias que podrías evitar. La principal es:

> *el día (hábil) **siguiente**... **después** del...*

Si es "el día siguiente", entonces es "el día después del otro día", así que no hace falta decir las dos cosas. Puedes elegir cualquiera de las dos (*siguiente* o *después*) y borrar la otra. La única diferencia será en la gramática, ya que luego de *siguiente* se utiliza la preposición *a*:

> *el día hábil **siguiente a**l de...*

mientras que con *después* se utiliza *de*:

> *el día hábil **después de**...*

Hay otra redundancia que puedes evitar. Si dices:

> *el **día** hábil después del **día** de la recogida del paquete*

estás repitiendo *día*. Puedes omitir esta palabra y decir simplemente:

> *el día hábil después del de la recogida del paquete*

Esto es posible porque *el* (*del* = *de* + *el*) no sólo es un artículo sino que puede referirse a un sustantivo en singular de género masculino nombrado anteriormente o implícito. Si fueran dos días diríamos:

> *dos días hábiles después del de la recogida del paquete*

quedando implícito que *del* significa *del día*.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones !

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría una construcción ligeramente distinta.

Por un lado, no hace falta repetir la palabra *día*, ni siquiera hacer referencia al día. *Después de la recogida* no tiene ninguna ambigüedad y es perfectamente claro, así que podemos simplificar la construcción.

Por otro lado, en castellano es más habitual la construcción *al día siguiente de* que *el día siguiente a*; pero no podemos decir *al día hábil siguiente de*. Mucho mejor, en este caso, usar otra construcción habitual, *el primer día hábil después de*, que tampoco tiene ninguna ambigüedad.

Por tanto, mi opción preferida es:

> "Aquellos envíos urgentes que realices online se entregarán el primer día hábil después de la recogida del paquete."

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!